# Typescript map string literal types to uppercase

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-conversion, typescript-typings

```js
type a = 'one' | 'two'
```

I would like to have a `type b` like

```js
type b = 'ONE' | 'TWO'
```

So I tried

```js
type a = 'one' | 'two'
type b = {[P in a]: P['toUpperCase']}
```

But that does not do what I want it to do.

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: I would be *very impressed* if this was possible. But I suspect it might not be.

Comment: Nope, no string manipulations in the type system.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is storing this `type a = 'one' | 'two'` on a separate file and the read the file content, then programmaticly change the values to uppercase.

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST I guess it works but seems a bit ugly. You might be able to have some sort of build step that transforms types, say takes all from `lowercase.d.ts` and generates an `uppercase.d.ts` with all the string literal types in uppercase there. But I'm not sure I really like this. Seems really easy to get in a tight bind with this if you need, say, first later capitalised only or anything other that deviates.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can now do this with the introduction of [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype):

```
type A = 'one' | 'two'
type B = Uppercase<A>

let b: B = 'one' // Type '"one"' is not assignable to type '"ONE" | "TWO"'.
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkB7AdhJUA+zgHcUkAoUSKAIQSgFUxIAnAYwEMBnCAHhgD5jiANhGBQARgC5K1JAHkAcgFESo6ekxQA9BqgQGDFA2IrESACoB1GcukEim7bv0MgA)

In addition to `Uppercase<StringType>`, there are also the following helper types:

- Lowercase
- Capitalize
- Uncapitalize

They can be used within a Template Literal Types, like below:

```
type Fruit = 'Apple' | 'Banana'
type FruitField = `fr_${Uncapitalize<Fruit>}`

const fruit: Record<FruitField, boolean> = {
    'fr_apple': true,
    'fr_banana': false,
    'fr_Apple': true, // error
    'fr_peach': false // error
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigcgIJjAGwkygB8sAhAQwDsbLMAoUSWRFGJCfAE3SgAMAZnAD6AEgDeAVWoBjSmBSV8SAF4QAPPGTAAfAF9+DBrID21AM6phOgFxQAShDNxuWtsA5duAGigAjU1NCGl0+CQYoKKxhEQUCIntgRAgfSOjMWP86Wkx7QWULVPSozNFcBLyoZIRUqAB6eqgIODhTOBKY0UhKWQALKoL8IoamlraO-SA)

Comment: The syntax has changed slightly for v4.1.0 beta, it's now `{uppercase A}`. 

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkB7AdhJUA+zgHcUkAoUSKAIQSgAMASAbwFcxIAnAYwEMBnaGAL41ixADYRgUAEYAuStSQB5AHIBRElIXpMxTYiQAVAOqKNCgkSA

Comment: With release v4.2 it's switched back to the way OP originally wrote it

Answer (score 5):

Here you have the link to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkB7AdhJUA%20zgHcUkAoUSKAIQSgFUxIAnAYwEMBnCAHhgD5jiANhGBQARgC5K1JAHkAcgFESo6ekzEViJABUA6jOXSCRIA)

And here the code:

```js
type A = 'one' | 'two'
type B = Uppercase<A>

let b: B = 'one' // Error
```

P.S. I don't get why in the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64421376/8548848) has been used a more complicated form to write the same thing

EDIT:
Derek Nguyen (best answer) has now changed his answer with the newer and more simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, IIRC during the 4.1 beta the manipulation types (uppercase<>, lowercase<>, etc.) only worked within the template literal